# mysql query how to check inarray with replaced string

Tags: mysql

how to write below condition in php mysql string format. 
column_1 contain value like `**2**`
tab.column_1 contain value line `**1***2***3***4**`

```
column_1 IN ( CONCAT("'", REPLACE(column_1,"***", "','"), "'") )
```

above write condition quotes showing error. any one have new idea.

Answer (score 2):

given that your values are all surrounded by `**` on either side in both `column_1` and `column_2` you could just use `LOCATE`:

```
LOCATE(column_1, column_2) > 0
```

For example

```
SELECT LOCATE('**2**', '**1***2***3***4**')
```

returns 5.

Comment: thank you so much brother i spend more than hours for solve this issue, now i got it